# Perl Regex to extract specific value from a single line

Tags: regex, perl

I hope you can help me.
I have the followig single line:

```
Total number of commands sent: <number_commands> : number_commands=6 Total number of Special commands sent: <number_commands> : number_commands=0 Total number of unknown commands: <number_commands> : number_commands=0 Total number of command parsing errors: <number_errors> : number_errors=1 Total number of fatal parsing errors: <number_errors> : number_errors=2
Total number of calls made to PROCESS1: <number_calls> : number_calls=0  Total number of calls made with time-out: <number_calls> : number_calls=7 Total number of calls ack by the PROCESS1: <number_calls> : number_calls=0 Total number of calls nack post-poned by the PROCESS1: <number_calls> : number_calls=5 Total number of calls nack rejected by the PROCESS1: <number_calls> : number_calls=5
```

I need to sum the number of errors, the number of unknown command and the number of nack.
From my example, the final result should be:

tot_nack= 10 (it should sum only the number_calls after the word nack) 
tot_timeout = 7 (it should sum only the number_calls after the word timeout) 
tot_errors = 3

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `(?=nack)(?:.*?number_calls=)(\d+?)`, `(?=time-out)(?:.*?number_calls=)(\d+?)` and `(?:number_errors=)(\d+?)`, match and get capture group #1.

Comment: Hi @xaleel, I have tried but it return always 1. Here the code. The line is inside an array here my code: `foreach my $line (@{$stdout_buf2}) {                      chomp $line;                      my $nack  = $line =~ m/(?=nack)(?:.*?number_calls=)(\d+?)/;                      print "Nack is $nack \n"; `                }

Comment: You can use this slightly modified one `(?<=nack([^=]*?)number_calls=)(\d+?)`, which will only match the digits. https://regexr.com/75pui